# argument 1 must be pygame.surface, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm programming a minor python game and some of my code doesn't seem to work. Have a look:

```
import pygame
import sys
import pygame.sprite as sprite
import time
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Uni Mario")


m_x = 100
m_y = 350
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

left=False
right=False
walk_count = 0
walkRight = []
walkLeft = []


myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 25)
screen_over = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 100)
hitcount = 0
score=0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30

background_image = pygame.image.load('Sprites/bg2.png')
background_size = background_image.get_size()
background_rect = background_image.get_rect()
sw = 837
sh = 464
win = pygame.display.set_mode((sw, sh))
w,h = background_size

t_x = sw
t_y = 350
g_x = sw-100

bg_x1 = 0
bg_y1 = 0

bg_x2 = w
bg_y2 = 0

d2 = 9999

def load_img(file_name): # loads the image, makes the pure white background transparent
    img = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()
    img.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

    return img

for i in range(1,7):
    walkLeft.append( load_img("Sprites/L" + str(i) + ".png" ) ) #loads in lists of images
    walkRight.append( load_img("Sprites/R" + str(i) + ".png") ) 

player_image = walkRight[0]

turtle_image = [pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba1.png'), pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba2.png'), pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba3.png')]
#turtle_small = pygame.transform.scale(turtle_image, (100, 60))

pygame.mixer.music.load('Music/Bros.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

left_idx=0
right_idx=0

#images = []
#images.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba1.png'))
#images.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba2.png'))
#images.append(pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba3.png'))

#index = 0
# 
#image = images[index]

#def update(images):
 #   index += 1

#if index >= len(images):
#    index = 0

#image = images[self.index]

run = True #main loop
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.time.delay(50)

    win.blit(background_image,(sw, sh)) #makes a scrolling background 
    pygame.display.update()

    bg_x2 -= 5
    bg_x1 -= 5
    if bg_x1 < sw - 2*w:
       bg_x1 = sw
    if bg_x2 < sw - 2*w:
          bg_x2 = sw

    t_x -=20
    if t_x < 0:
        t_x = sw

    #g_x -= 20
    #if g_x < 0:
     #   g_x = sw+500



    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and m_x > vel: 
        m_x -= vel
        if not isJump:
            player_image = walkLeft[left_idx]
            left_idx += 1
            if left_idx >= len(walkLeft):
                left_idx=0

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and m_x < sw - width - vel:
        m_x += vel
        if not isJump:
            player_image = walkRight[right_idx]
            right_idx += 1
            if right_idx >= len(walkRight):
                right_idx=0

    if not(isJump):      
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            isJump = True
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            m_y -= (jumpCount ** 2)* 0.25 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    if bg_x1 > -w:        
        win.blit(background_image,(bg_x1,bg_y1))
    if bg_x2 > -w:
        win.blit(background_image,(bg_x2,bg_y2))
    win.blit(player_image, (m_x,m_y))

    win.blit(turtle_image, (t_x, t_y)) #22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222



    label = myfont.render("Hit Count = "+ str(hitcount), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(label, ((sw-200), 420))

    label3 = myfont.render("If your hit count gets",1, (0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(label3, (270, 10))

    label4= myfont.render("to 3, you lose.", 1, (0 , 0, 0))
    win.blit(label4, (270, 60))

    label5 = myfont.render("Score: "+ str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(label5, ((sw-180), 50))


    pygame.display.update() 


    d2 = (t_x - m_x)**2 + (t_y - m_y)**2 #represents the distance between the two character
    if d2 < 142: #keep it at 142, it seems to be a good distance for the hitcount
        hitcount += 1
    else:
        score += 1/10
    if hitcount >= 3:
        label2 = screen_over.render("Game Over", 1, (255, 0, 0))
        win.blit(label2, (230, 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(2)
        run= False
    if score >= 100:
        label6 = screen_over.render("YOU WIN", 1, (255, 0, 0))
        win.blit(label6, (230,200))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(5)
        run=False

pygame.quit()
```

Yeah.... So the error reads:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\aryaat\Desktop\SPython Gaming Project\Uni Mario(A).py", line 163, in <module>
>     win.blit(turtle_image, (t_x, t_y)) #22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`turtle_image` is not an `pygame.Surface` object, but it is a list of `pygame.Surface` objects:

> ```py
> turtle_image = [pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba1.png'), pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba2.png'), pygame.image.load('Sprites/Goomba3.png')]
> ```

You've to select an object from the list by the use of the index operator (e.g. `turtle_image[0]`) which you want to "blit" to the window surface:

```py
win.blit(turtle_image[0], (t_x, t_y))
```